# Help selecting procedures in spss

Tags: spss

I have two data sets for employee engagement taken at different times.
Effectively each person is engaged, passive or disengaged.
Engaged =1 
Passive = 2
Disengaged = 3

Survey windows are
June survey =1
August survey =2

I want to run tests to understand the following:
Whether the number of people in each engagement group is statistically different across each survey i.e. number of engaged in june is statistically different to the number of engaged in August. Same for passive and disengaged.

I would also like to understand how to calculate what the confidence intervals are for the data so I can figure out if X is +/- bigger than Y whether it will be significant.

Hope ive provided enough info.

let me know if i haven't.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can explain more precisely what kind of confidence interval you have in mind, so that someone can comment on that. I hope my answer covers the rest. You can compare key parts of the procedure in R with the same parts of the output from SPSS.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following 'contingency table' of observed counts:

```
       Eng   Pas   Dis    TOT  
Jun    343   111    97    551
Aug    412   213   121    747
TOT    756   324   218   1298
```

Then the test statistic is

$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{(X_{ij}-E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}},$$
is approximately distributed as $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = (2-1)(3-1) = 2),$
where $X_{ij}$ are the counts in the table, and $E_{ij}$ are found
by multiplication from row and column totals. For example,
$E_{11} = 1298\frac{551}{1298}\frac{756}{1298}.$ [The approximation
is reasonably good as long as 'most' $E_{ij} > 5$ and all exceed $3.]$

I do not use SPSS, but I can show computations in R, leading to $Q = 11.91.$ [Perhaps see [this link](https://libguides.library.kent.edu/SPSS/Crosstabs) for some output from SPSS for 'chi-squared contingency tables'.]

```
Jun = c(343, 111, 97)
Aug = c(413, 213, 121)
TAB = rbind(Jun, Aug)
chi.cont = chisq.test(TAB)
chi.cont

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT
X-squared = 11.91, df = 2, p-value = 0.002593

chi.cont$obs
    [,1] [,2] [,3]                   # Echo observed counts
Jun  343  111   97
Aug  413  213  121
chi.cont$exp
        [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
Jun 320.9214 137.5378  92.54083      # Show expected counts
Aug 435.0786 186.4622 125.45917
chi.cont$resi
         [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
Jun  1.232457 -2.262836  0.4635399   # Pearson residuals
Aug -1.058491  1.943429 -0.3981096
```

The nine Pearson residuals' are $R_{ij} = (X_{ij} - E_{ij})/\sqrt{E_{ij}},$ so that $Q = \sum_i \sum_j R_{ij}^2$, is the sum of the nine 'contributions' to 
the chi-squared statistic.

The probability to the right of $Q = 11.91$ under the density curve
of  $\mathsf{Chisq}(2)$ is the P-value. The null hypothesis that Time and
Engagement categories are independent is rejected at the 5% level of significance because P-value the $0.0026 < 0.05.$

Alternatively, the critical value $c = 9.488$ cuts probability $0.05$ from the upper tail of $\mathsf{Chisq}(2)$ so that we reject the null hypothesis because
$Q = 11.91.$  The critical value can be found in printed tables of chi-squared distributions, or using software as below:

```
qchisq(.95, 4)
[1] 9.487729
```

The figure shows the density function of $\mathsf{Chisq}(2).$ Vertical lines show the positions of $Q$ (solid) and $c$ (dotted).

[image]

The Pearson residuals can help to interpret the results of such a chi-squared test. Look for residuals with absolute values of about 2 or more. They
help to track the most important differences between observed and expected counts. In this case, the Passive category seems to have different proportions of subjects; for example, under the null hypothesis we might have expected
about 138 Passive subjects in June, but we saw only 111.